# dynamically rename data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to dynamically create datasets:

```
def CreateDF (indsn, outdsn):
    outdsn = pd.DataFrame(indsn)
    ....
    return outdsn

CreateDF (phase_df, phase_df2)
```

But it does not work, I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'phase_df2' is not defined

Being able to do the above could be useful because I could also loop through a list of datasets (for each datasets in the list), but I'm not sure how to dynamically rename them.

Comment: error is pretty clear what is `phase_df2` here as your code snippet doesn't show where this is declared

Comment: You need to show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your code has nothing to do with the error you are getting.

Comment: Well that error doesn't have anything to do with your function. It just means that you never defined phase2_df

Comment: if we take the example below:   

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*5).reshape(2,5))
df.columns=['blah','blah2','blah3','blah','blah']

we then want to rename df to dfnew...

def CreateDF (indsn, outdsn):
    outdsn = pd.DataFrame(indsn)
    return outdsn

CreateDF (df, dfnew) 

I was hoping for being able to pass the new name 'dfnew' as a new name for df..

Comment: @tezzaaa the error `NameError: name 'phase_df2' is not defined` means the variable `phase_df2` is not defined, please show us the code that can reproduce that error.

Comment: You're trying to dynamically declare variables, if I'm getting that right.  They just happen to be dataframe objects; regardless, that isn't something you can/should do.  Instead consider appending dataframes to a list, or making them dictionary entries.

Comment: yes you are correct that's what i'm trying to do. phase_df2 is not defined as i want to create it using the function

Comment: Yes, don't do that.  Here, I'll write up an example as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little sparse because you didn't give us info on why this needs to happen, or what your source material looks like, but the general idea is:

```
def make_df(name):
    ...
    return df

dict_of_dfs = dict()
df_names = []        #a list of all the dataframes you want to create

for name in df_names:
    dict_of_dfs[name] = make_df(name)
```

Now instead of variables, you can name dictionary entries as keys and each value will be the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise df:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,4),columns=['A','B','C','D'], dtype='object')
```

dynamically add:

```
for values in values_np
    df.set_value([iterator, 'A', values)
    iterator += 1
```

This way you can dynamically add row wise